# Use a configuration file with Python executables

Tags: python, configuration, pyinstaller, executable

I have two python files: `Project_1.py` is the main file. `config.py` is the configuration file which contains the location paths. When I run `project_1` locally it works perfect. It constantly moves files from location A to Location B exactly as I wanted.

So my goal was to create a python executable of the above program, so I did this: `pyinstaller --onefile -w project_1.py` in cmd.

So I copied `project_1.exe,` `config_py` and the data in `LocationA` and `LocationB` to a new environment (OS windows, but without Python):

[image]

So I adjusted the paths in `config.py` with notepad++ to the new paths in the new environment and tried to run `project_1.exe` by double clicking on it. This is what I got:
[image]

**This is the source code of `project_1.py` locally:**

```
import os
import shutil
import config as cfg

def move_files(source, destination):   
    files = os.listdir(source)
    for f in files:
        f_path = os.path.join(source, f)
        shutil.move(f_path, destination)

if len(os.listdir(cfg.location_a)) == 0:
    move_files(cfg.location_b, cfg.location_a)
elif len(os.listdir(cfg.location_b)) == 0:
    move_files(cfg.location_a, cfg.location_b)
```

**This is the source code of `config.py` locally:**

```
location_a = r'C:\Users\FFF\Desktop\Learn Airflow\pythonproject\LocationA'
location_b = r'C:\Users\FFF\Desktop\Learn Airflow\pythonproject\LocationB'
```

I don't have a clue what is going on, it seems like the `config.py` does not seem to be recognized but I don't know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing external module in single-file exe created with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350078/importing-external-module-in-single-file-exe-created-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: Alternatively (to explain why relative paths might not work the way you expect): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487825/setting-working-directory-of-a-converted-py-file-to-exe-file

Comment: No it does not answer my question as my case is more specific.

Comment: In your `project_1.py`, add a `print(cfg.__file__)` just after the import so you can see which file is loaded. It may not be the same `config.py`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel where will it be printed?

Comment: you might have to recompile with the new config.py file I think. The config.py probably got compiled with the exe and it is looking at the old paths. Just a guess though.

Comment: What's more specific about your case? You're trying to import your `config.py` from a script that has been turned into an exectuable. That won't work unless you exclude the `config.py` from your executable build and modify the location it's looking for the `config.py`, exactly as per the linked question.

Comment: Try it without the -w switch so that you have a console where the print writes to.

Comment: Leave the `print()` but to know why the app is failing, you have to have a console to which you can see the error code, it might be happening so fast and you may need to capture it with a screen recorder or something

Comment: @Kemp Did this: `pyinstaller --onefile excludes=['config.py'] project_1.py` is an invalid syntax, doesnt work...

Comment: @CoolCloud could you join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232816/discussion

Comment: That goes in your pyinstaller spec file, not on the command line. If you check the [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) the equivalent argument appears to be `--exclude-module` if you don't want to use a spec file.

Comment: @Kemp can you show me the solution regarding my case in code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016479/python-configparser-nosectionerror-no-section)

Comment: @CoolCloud, no I always use raw strings.